# undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:... > (RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add comments to my photos model however when I submit my comment I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdef11c3dd8>:0x007fdef4163f98>
```

My routes look like this:

```
resources :photos do
  resources :comments
end
```

Models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :photo
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

views new comment:

```
<%= form_for [@picture, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :comments %>
  <%= f.text_area :comments %>
  <%= f.submit 'Leave Comment' %>
<% end %>
```

views index:

```
<% if @photos.any? %>
  <% @photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to photo.title, photo_path(photo) %>
    <%= photo.description %>
      <% if photo.comments.any? %>
       <ul>
         <% photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
          <li>
          <%= comment.comments %>
        </li>
        <% end %>
       <% else %>
       <p> No comments yet </p>
    <% end %>

    <% if current_user %>
      <%= link_to "Comment on #{photo.title}", new_photo_comment_path(photo) %>
      <% if current_user.id == photo.user_id %>
        <%= link_to "Delete #{photo.title}", photo_path(photo), method: :delete %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <br>

  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No photos yet
<% end %>

<br>
<%= link_to "Add a photo", new_photo_path %>
```

Comments Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
    @comment = Comment.new
  end

  def create
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])
    @photo.comments.create(comment_params)
    redirect_to photos_path
  end

  def review_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:comments)
  end

end
```

Please let me know if you need any further info, haven't posted much so still getting used to the format. Thanks all.

EDIT: Here is the error I am getting in full:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jeAn.png)

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see all your paths and their helper names. From what your routes tell, the method will be `photo_comments_path` and needs a parameter to specify the photo.

Comment: Hi sorry I'm a bit confused, I've run rake routes and the 'new' action has a prefix of new_photo_comment which I have been using as I want to create a new comment. What does photo_comments_path have to do with this as that related to the index and create actions in routes. Thanks.

Comment: since the error is complaining about the `comments_path` method, you must be using it in some view. Look for the view where this method is used for and add it to the question please.

Comment: comments_path is not in my code anywhere, I have used the search function and it is not showing anything. I have added a picture of the error message that I am getting: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3jeAn.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the comments view:

```
<%= form_for [@picture, @comment] do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :comments %>
  <%= f.text_area :comments %>
  <%= f.submit 'Leave Comment' %>
<% end %>
```

@picture was meant to be @photo. doh.